# Having two actionbars in android?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-actionbar

I currently have a action bar with multiple tabs that swaps between different fragments. I'm looking to have another "action bar" that sits underneath that does the same thing, what would be the easiest way to do this?

edit: thought i should clarify that this is what i have now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aus8s.png, and this is what i want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXTz2.png

Answer (score 0):

```
// Custom action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        title.setText("Profile");
```

### action_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

</TextView>
```

Comment: But I already have a custom actionbar? I already have something like this http://imgur.com/kYtpUzt, and I want to make a second actionbar appear when i click on a certain tab like this http://imgur.com/q2DYIJT